# Navigation menu toggle dropdown not rendering properly

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am having difficulty in rendering the dropdown menu properly on my website [www.bg-hairsalon.com](http://www.bg-hairsalon.com) It is a wordpress website that utilizes the theme `Zerif-Lite`. It doesn't show the options when I click on the navigation button. However, if I scroll down and then click on the navigation toggle button it displays the menu. I am using android and iphone both to test my website. If you could take a look that would be great. I was using android to test this menu. This doesn't work on iphone as well.

The code I am using for the navigation menu so far is as follows:
Not sure how much of this code do I need.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
.navbar {
background: #FFF;
border: 0;
border-radius: 0 !important;
text-align: left;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 11px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.08);
box-shadow: 0px 5px 11px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.08);
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
#main-nav {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1000;
min-height: 75px;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
#main-nav.fixed {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
}
}

.nav li a.nav-active {
color: #b8db4d !important;
}
.nav li a.nav-active:before {
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
z-index: 1;
content: "";
width: 75%;
height: 2px;
background: #b8db4d;
bottom: 0px;
left: 12.5%;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav >li {
display: inline;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-top: 20px;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li:last-child {
margin-right: 0 !important;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
color: #404040;
padding: 0;
line-height: 35px;
}
.navbar-inverse .main-navigation ul > li {
display: inline;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-top: 20px;
}
.navbar-inverse .main-navigation > ul > li:last-child {
margin-right: 0 !important;
}
.navbar-inverse .main-navigation > ul > li > a {
color: #404040;
padding: 0;
line-height: 35px;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav ul.sub-menu {
display: none;
position: absolute; top: 100%;
background:#fff;
width:200px;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.08);
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav ul.sub-menu {
margin:0;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav ul.sub-menu ul.sub-menu{
position: absolute;
left:100%;
top:0;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav ul.sub-menu li {
float: none;
position: relative;
list-style:none;
padding:10px;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav ul.sub-menu li a {
color:#404040;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav ul.sub-menu li:hover > a {
color:#b8db4d;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav li:hover > ul.sub-menu {
display: block;
}

.navbar-brand {
height: 76px;
position: relative;
line-height: 45px;
}
.current a {
color: #b8db4d !important;
position: relative;
outline: none;
}
.current:before {
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
z-index: 1;
content: "";
width: 75%;
height: 2px;
background: #b8db4d;
bottom: 0px;
left: 12.5%;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
color: #b8db4d;
outline: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
.navbar-toggle {
border: 0;
background-color: #808080;
margin-top: 23px;
}
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover,.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus {
background-color: #b8db4d;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 1;
box-shadow: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
.navbar-toggle.active{
background-color: #b8db4d !important;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
.navbar-toggle.collapsed{
background-color: #808080 !important;
}
}
```

Comment: In pc its works good but you have 1 jquery error . Solve that and might be your issue will be resolve.

Comment: Try to add these lines from solution here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/224661/annoying-jqmigrate-migrate-is-in-console-after-update-to-wp-4-5

Comment: Can you please let me know what is that error ?

Comment: I added that but the problem persists.

Comment: you are getting error in iphone/android or in pc?

Comment: I am not getting error. I did clean my history and cache. The only issue is when I open the website and click on the menu nothing happens. But it gives options only if i scroll down. Same behavior on my Note 4 and Iphone 5. In iphone 5, the menu is not sticky. I want the menu to be sticky on all the devices. Do I need to add iphone specific code ?

Also I want to reduce the spacing between the address on the top and the slider. I couldn't do that. Thanks.